# I'm struggling to delete words in Vim

Tags: vim

My cursor is on the final character of a word in Vim. Without moving the cursor, is there any succinct way to delete the current word and the word before it?

As far as I can tell, the only way to delete the *current* word is to use `diw`. Using `db` leaves the character under the cursor (which happens to be the last character).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do either `2dbx` or `vbbd`. Or `v5bd` if there were 5 words to delete.

I prefer `vbbd` as I like to have some visual clue of what I'm going to do and it feels a bit cleaner.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize that the final character would be highlighted in visual mode, considering it is *not* highlighted in normal mode. I had always assumed that operators had the same meaning in visual mode.

Comment: Yes, visual selection always includes the current character. I think it's more logical than `d`'s behaviour to include the current character when going to the right and exclude it when going to the left. This behaviour is quite coherent with `y` and `c`'s own behaviour but (IMHO) not really with the general idea of "the cursor is ON a letter". This "discrepancy" is another reason why I like to use visual selection.

Answer (score 1):

Backward moving actions, (like `db`) take effect from the boundary in front of the cursor.

Probably your easiest way to do this is something like `xd2b` - that takes care of the character under the cursor first.

Generally I prefer to use `Bdw` (or `wdB`) when deleting whole words, as this doesn't leave you with a double space where the word was. Obviously this depends on the context of your actions, and what else you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you take care of the character under the word first, then the second to last character *becomes* the first, and *it* is left behind. `d2bxx` works (with the `x`s at the end), but it feels clunky.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. With the cursor on the last character of the word, as per the OP, `x` deletes the char, and leaves the cursor on the space/punctuation after the word. `d2b` then works fine. The only times this **doesn't** work, are if the word is the last one on the line, or the word is only a single character. 

Like I said in my answer - it depends on context. 

Also: I've edited the above as `wde` and `edw` are wrong (they delete the **next** word).

Answer (score 0):

`d2vb` is one option. The added `v` modifies the motion to also delete the character under the cursor.

Details:

> Vim makes a distinction between inclusive and exclusive motion. `v`
> toggles the "inclusiveness" or "exclusiveness" of a motion. For an
> example of toggling the opposite direction (inclusive => exclusive),
> try it with `e`:
>
> `dve`
>
> See `:help` inclusive for an explication. Until now, you thought it
> was just esoteric nonsense! Didn't you? Didn't you?! (At least, my
> eyes glazed over whenever I used to read that section in the help...
> :)

[Source.](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/24wbuz/command_to_delete_one_full_word_backwards/chbbkfk/)